# bean validation get parameter jsf

Tags: validation, jsf, bean-validation

Using bean validation like:

```
@Size(max = 5)
private String name;
```

How do I retrieve the `max` value to use within my JSF site? For example to set maxlength value in input text component.

Comment: [MyFaces ExtVal](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/validator/) does this kind of stuff automagically.

Comment: That looks promising. Still deciding if I should switch to bean validation right now. Is there a stable primefaces implementation which sets those view related properties for primefaces components? But this only partially answers the question. Sometimes the component visual limitations depend on combinations of multiple values. For example: `max=#{el:minimum(order.count + stock.count, maxOrderCount)}`

Comment: It was a comment, not an answer :) Never really used bean validation and so on, so can't answer from experience / top-of-head.